# Which armour gives a larger boost to ancient weapons?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Assuming I'm using ancient weapons, and have the barbarian armour set and ancient armour set upgraded twice, which set will I do more damage with with regular attacks, and which with charge attacks (since the barb set boosts those on top of it's attack up bonuses)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The Ancient Armor Set will enable you to deal more damage, assuming you're using Ancient weapons.** The Ancient Armor Set boosts your damage by 80% if you're using ancient weapons. The Barbarian Armor Set boosts your damage by 50% for all weapons.

The Barbarian Armor Set doesn't increase your charge attack damage - it reduces the amount of stamina you use to perform a charge attack. You'll still do more charge attack damage with the Ancient Armor Set, assuming you're using Ancient weapons.

### Sources

- [Barbarian Armor Attack Stat Boosts @ Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/643dyp/barbarian_armor_attack_stat_boosts/)
- [Ancient Armor and Ancient Weapons Attack Boosts @ Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/zelda/comments/667zk3/botw_ancient_armor_and_ancient_weapons_attack/)
- [Armor @ Gamepedia](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Armor)
- [What's stronger? Barbarian Set or Ancient Set with Guardian or Ancient weapons? @ GameFAQs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75111996)

Comment: Also, I think you can use an attack damage elixir or meal along with the ancient armor to essentially stack the attack bonuses.

Comment: @JoshB. Yep, but only Ancient Proficiency. Technically the Attack Damage boost stacks as well, but it maxes out at 3 for both sources taken together, so potions are useless on a full Barbarian set.